# Polynomial Time Complexity O(N)

Tags: algorithm, limit, computer-science, complexity-theory

Ive been asked the following question

```
which of the following are not a polynomial time complexity:
A: O(N)
B: O(N!)
C: O(N log(N))
D: O(1)
E: O(log N)
```

I think the answer is B and D but I'm unsure about C as the syntax doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: [Polynomial Time Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#:~:text=An%20algorithm%20is%20said%20to%20be%20of%20polynomial%20time%20if,for%20some%20positive%20constant%20k.) is usually presented as an upper-bounds limit, so that would mean that only (B) is not in polynomial time complexity.

Comment: Usually an algorithm is described to run in polynomial time (which means its runtime bounded by a polynomial). Did your course material define what it means for a complexity class to be polynomial? There's two obvious definitions -- one is that all the members of that class are polynomial in the usual sense (so A,C,D,E are all polynomial by this definition), and the other is that the class can be described by a polynomial (so only A and D are polynomial by this definition). Neither of the definitions is standard.

Comment: What is wrong with C ??